# Shorten Code Add Dictionary with condition

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
if(TextBox1.Text != "")
{
    items.Add(TextBox1.Name, TextBox1.Text);
}
if (TextBox2.Text != "")
{
    items.Add(TextBox2.Name, TextBox2.Text);
}
if (TextBox3.Text != "")
{
    items.Add(TextBox3.Name, TextBox3.Text);
}
```

It's working fine but there are about 20 `TextBox` items and I want to reduce redudancy. Is there a way to make this shorter?

Comment: Define a function/method that takes a `Dictionary` and a `TextBox` as parameters.

Comment: You can get the list of all textboxes in your UI. How you can get this list depends upon what type of UI you are working on (Web or Windows etc). Once you have that list then its matter of converting that list into dictionary using Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the TextBoxes into a collection and then use LINQ:

```
TextBox[] allTxt = {TextBox1,TextBox12,TextBox3,...};

Dictionary<string, string> items = allTxt
    .Where(txt => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
    .ToDictionary(txt => txt.Name, txt => txt.Text);
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` - can the `Text` property of a `TextBox` ever be `null`?

Comment: @Dr.Snail: i don't think so(although not impossible), but i prefer the method anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Controls` collection of a form and filter it out based on a type of a control using `OfType` method and then convert it to dictionary:

```
var tbs = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(tb => ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
    .ToDictionary(tb => tb.Name, tb => tb.Text);
```

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to add all TextBoxes. This also doesn't search recursively, for example if the TextBox is in a Panel or GroupBox

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array that contains all the textboxes and use `Where` and `ToDictionary`

```
var dic = new[] { TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5 }
    .Where(t => t.Text != "")
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function for that.

```
public function test(TextBox text)
{
    if(text.Text != "")
    {
        items.Add(text.Name, text.Text);
    }
}
```

In your main function, just call this function above like this

```
test(TextBox1);
```

Comment: What syntax is that?

Comment: `items` isn't global

Comment: 'items' should be passed in as parameter to the 'test' method.